# Find the Basis for the kernel of T, and find the basis for the image of T

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

The function *T* is given by

*T(M)* = *M*$\begin{bmatrix}1, 2\\0, 1\end{bmatrix}$ - $\begin{bmatrix}1, 2\\0, 1\end{bmatrix}$*M*

this is one part of a question (part c), and the part before this (part b) asks for the basis matrix *B* of *T* with respect to the basis

*basis* = ($\begin{bmatrix}1, 0\\0, 1\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}0, 1\\0, 0\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}1, 0\\0, -1\end{bmatrix}$)

for which I found *B* = $\begin{bmatrix}0, 0, 0\\0, 0, 4\\0,0,0\end{bmatrix}$ by plugging the *basis* into *T* and taking constant multiples out of each product so that it was some constant *c* times each one of the bases, and those constants *c* were then the columns of *B*, if that makes sense..

**My main problem is I don't know what to find the kernel of (i.e. do I find the kernel of *B* since that's the basis matrix of *T*? or do I need some other matrix?) and I'm also kind of thrown off by the basis in part b, if that has anything to do with this part.**

I appreciate any help at all! Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the `bmatrix` environment, you are supposed to use `&` as a separator rather than `,`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to find the kernel of $T$ directly. However, it should be noted that basis was specifically chosen in order to make it easier to find the kernel using $B$.  So, with that said:

We begin by finding the nullspace of the matrix $B$.  That is, we want the solutions to the equation $Bx = 0$.  Without too much effort, you should find that the elements of the nullspace are the vectors of the form $x = x_1(1,0,0) + x_2(0,1,0) = (x_1,x_2,0)$ (the vectors here are column vectors written sideways for my convenience).

Now, let's translate this solution into a statement about $T$. Let $M_1,M_2,M_3$ denote the matrices of the given basis.  The entire point of the matrix $B$ is that we have
$$
T(x_1 M_1 + x_2 M_2 + x_3 M_3) = y_1 M_1 + y_2 M_2 + y_3 M_3 \iff B \pmatrix{x_1\\x_2\\x_3} = \pmatrix{y_1\\y_2\\y_3}.
$$
So, by finding the solutions to $Bx = 0$, we have found all $x_1,x_2,x_3$ for which $M = x_1 M_1 + x_2 M_2 + x_3 M_3$ satisfies $T(M) = 0$. In other words, we have described all matrices $M$ of *the kernel* of $T$.  In particular, we can say that $M$ is an element of the kernel iff its coordinate vector has the form $(x_1,x_2,0) = x_1\cdot (1,0,0) + x_2\cdot(0,1,0)$, which holds iff 
$$
M = x_1 M_1 + x_2 M_2 = \pmatrix{x_1&x_2\\0&x_1}.
$$
Likewise, we can use the column space of $B$ to describe the image of $T$. The column space of $B$ consists of elements of the form $(0,t,0)$ for some $t \in \Bbb R$. Correspondingly, the image of $T$ consists of elements of the form $t M_2$ for some $t \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: so does that mean the basis wrt ker(T) is the span of x_1 and x_2?  I'm a little confused..

Comment: @grace $x_1$ and $x_2$ are numbers, so it doesn't really make sense to say "the span of $x_1$ and $x_2$" here. Do you understand the connection between $\ker(T)$ and the nullspace of $B$?  Do you know what the term "coordinate vector" means?

Comment: I know kernel and null space refer to the same idea; I think I worded my question wrong, sorry I meant would the basis wrt ker(T) be the column vectors (1,0,0) and (0,1,0)? I'm looking at notes I have and I see that what you did with x1 and x2 and such looks like defining coordinates.  Would the column vector (x1, x2, 0) be the coordinate vector?

Comment: @grace typically, the "kernel" is connected to a linear transformation, and the "nullspace" is connected to a matrix.  Under this definition, the matrix can be thought of as a linear transformation whose kernel is the nullspace of the matrix.  But yes: if the term "kernel of a matrix" makes sense to you, then it's the same thing as the nullspace in this context.

Comment: @grace Note that the $T$ is a linear transformation over a vector space $V$ that consists of $2 \times 2$ matrices. The kernel of $T$ needs to be a subspace of $V$. That is, the kernel of $T$ is a set of matrices in this case, not a set of $3 \times 1$ vectors.  However, the $3 \times 1$ vectors $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ form a basis of the nullspace/kernel of $B$.

Comment: @grace The point of coordinate vectors is that the column vector $(x_1,x_2,0)$ represents a specific element of our vector space $V$. Specifically, $(x_1,x_2,0)$ is the vector that corresponds to the matrix $x_1 M_1 + x_2 M_2$.

Comment: @grace I've fixed some typos in my answer; it might be easier to read now.

Comment: So would the basis of the kernel of B be the same as that of T? since we found B using T?

Comment: @grace You seem to be missing a key point. The elements in the kernel of $B$ are vectors (with three entries). The elements of the kernel of $T$ are matrices. So, the kernels are not the same since their elements are different kinds of things.

Comment: oh, okay... so then what would the basis for the kernel of T look like? I understand how we get ker(B) but then what am I doing to get it to be the basis for ker(T)?

Comment: $M_1$ is the matrix corresponding to $(1,0,0)$, and $M_2$ is the matrix corresponding to $(0,1,0)$. So, because $(1,0,0),(0,1,0)$ form a basis of the nullspace of $B$, $M_1,M_2$ form a basis of the kernel of $T$.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, thank you so much for you help!